# Numpy array (matrix) with one axis indices being strings

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, matrix

In numpy one can create a matrix and use the handy slice notation

```
arr=np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7, 8, 9], [10,11,12]])
print (arr[2, :])
print (arr[1:2, 2])
```

And this can be extended up to N dimensions.

But what now if one I wish to have the same thing, but one axis is instead of being a numeric axis, it is a string-based axis? So indexing an element would be like:

```
print(arr["cylinder", :, :]) #prints all cylinders
print(arr["sphere", 4, 100]) #prints sphere of 4 radius, 100 bar
print(arr[:, 4, 100]) #prints every shape with 4 radius 100 bar
```

I could make for each "combination" (all shapes, specific radius, specific pressure ... all shapes, all radii, specific pressure ... specific shape, specific radius, specific pressure). A unique function but that is infeasible, so how can I create this?

Currently everything is stored as dictionaries of dictionaries (especially because only values for radius and pressure are used). If the underlying storage could be kept as dictionaries of dictionaries - but adding the slice/index operators that woudl be golden!

---

current code (and yes I do have the idea to look into kwargs to make the current codebase better for adding new points) - this is just added to prevent the "NP" problem issue:

```
class all_measurements(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.measurements = {}

    def add_measurement(self, measurement):
        shape = measurement.shape
        size = measurement.size
        pressure = measurement.pressure
        fname = measurement.filename
        if shape in self.measurements:
            shape_dict = self.measurements[shape]
        else:
            shape_dict = {}
            self.measurements[shape] = shape_dict

        if size in shape_dict:
            size_dict = shape_dict[size]
        else:
            size_dict ={}
            shape_dict[size] = size_dict

        if pressure in size_dict:
            pressure_dict = size_dict[pressure]
        else:
            pressure_dict = {}
            size_dict[pressure] = pressure_dict

        if fname in pressure_dict:
            print("adding same file twice!")

        pressure_dict[fname] = measurement

    def get_measurements(self, shape = None, size = None, pressure = None, fname = None):
        current_dict = self.measurements
        if shape is None:
            return current_dict
        if shape in current_dict:
            current_dict = current_dict[shape]
        else:
            return None

        if size is None:
            return current_dict
        if size in current_dict:
            current_dict = current_dict[size]
        else:
            return None

        if pressure is None:
            return current_dict
        if pressure in current_dict:
            current_dict = current_dict[pressure]
        else:
            return None

        if fname is None:
            return current_dict
        if fname in current_dict:
            return current_dict[fname]
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: I think you are mixing mappings with indexing.  Apart from the field names of structured arrays, indices just count the row and/or column.  They don't have labels, numeric or otherwise.

Comment: You can add `__getitem__` and `__getslice__` methods to your class to get indexing syntax.  Of course it's your responsibility to interpret the index or slice, and return the correct item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repeated use of a pattern like:

```
    if shape in self.measurements:
        shape_dict = self.measurements[shape]
    else:
        shape_dict = {}
        self.measurements[shape] = shape_dict
```

suggests that you could profitably use a `collections.defaultdict`.

When I fill your `all_measurements` object with some `measurements` (using my own simple class),

```
A = all_measurements()
A.add_measurement(measurement('round',10,20.0,'test0'))
A.add_measurement(measurement('square',10,30.0,'test1'))
A.add_measurement(measurement('round',1,20.0,'test2'))
print(A.measurements)
```

I get a dictionary that looks like:

```
{'square': {10: {30.0: {'test1': measurement: square,10,30.0,test1}}},
 'round': {1: {20.0: {'test2': measurement: round,1,20.0,test2}}, 
           10: {20.0: {'test0': measurement: round,10,20.0,test0}}}}
```

I don't see anything that looks like a 3d array here.

I suppose if there were a standard set of shapes, sizes, and pressures, eg

```
shapes = ['round', 'square', 'flat']
sizes = [1,3,10,20]
pressures = [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]
```

you could construct a 3d array, e.g.

```
np.empty((3,4,3))
```

and dictionaries or lists of tuples that map the labels to the indices, e.g.

```
sizemap={1:0, 3:1, 10:2, 20:3}
sizelist=[(1,0),(3,1)...]
```

But what would be the values of this array?  The `measurement` objects?  `ndarrays` of type object are possible, but usually don't have advantages over nested lists or dictionaries.

---

I tested your `get_measurements`.  As structured now, you have to select shape, and then among those select size, etc.  It can't return all shapes with a specific size value.

This method, lets me use indexing, including slicing, syntax to pass arguments to your `get_measurements`:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    print(key)
    key = list(key)  # comes in a tuple
    for i,k in enumerate(key):
        if isinstance(k, slice):
            # code to interpret a slice goes here
            key[i] = None # fall back, do nothing
    return self.get_measurements(*key)

pprint(A['round',10])
pprint(A[:,10])
pprint(A['round':'square', 10:30:10])
```

produces

```
('round', 10)
{20.0: {'test0': measurement: round,10,20.0,test0}}

(slice(None, None, None), 10)
{'round': ...}

(slice('round', 'square', None), slice(10, 30, 10))
{'round': ...}
```

You'd have to decide what objects like

```
slice('round','square', None)
slice(10, 30, 10)
```

mean in the context of your attributes

Comment: The idea is to quickly get "statistical"  data: ie get all measurements that are square. Or all measurements that have 60 bars. Or size of 4mm. Or a combinations of 2 parameters. (like get all measurements that are both a square and are done with 100 bar pressure).

Comment: That sounds more like database problem than an array one.  Arrays are for cases where there is one value for each possible combination of those parameters (with the possibility of `None`).

Comment: I sketched how indexing and slicing might be added to your class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you look for structured arrays, see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.zeros(10,dtype={'names':['a','b','c'],'formats':['f64','f64','f64']})

# write some data in a
>>> a['a'] = np.arange(10)
>>> a['b'] = np.arange(10,20)
>>> a['c'] = np.arange(20,30)

>>> a
array([(0.0, 10.0, 20.0), 
       (1.0, 11.0, 21.0), 
       (2.0, 12.0, 22.0),
       (3.0, 13.0, 23.0), 
       (4.0, 14.0, 24.0), 
       (5.0, 15.0, 25.0),
       (6.0, 16.0, 26.0), 
       (7.0, 17.0, 27.0), 
       (8.0, 18.0, 28.0),
       (9.0, 19.0, 29.0)], 
  dtype=[('a', '<f4'), ('b', '<f4'), ('c', '<f4')])

>>> a['a'][2:6]
array([ 2.,  3.,  4.,  5.], dtype=float32)

>>> a[4:8]
array([(4.0, 14.0, 24.0), 
       (5.0, 15.0, 25.0), 
       (6.0, 16.0, 26.0),
       (7.0, 17.0, 27.0)], 
  dtype=[('a', '<f4'), ('b', '<f4'), ('c', '<f4')])
```